# ''cat | tr <file1'' -- why does cat wait for input instead of reading from file1?

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin, tr

I'm working on recreating my own shell environment copied from bash, and I found a pretty weird behavior with the real bash: when I enter

```
cat | tr -d 'o' < file1
(file1 contains only the text "Bonjour")
```

It outputs `Bnjur`, so until here no problem but it stays in a 'waiting for input' state until I press enter. At first I thought it was `cat` reading on `stdin` after `tr` execution, but it doesn't behave the same, it just waits for the user to press enter and (apparently) does nothing.
I saw on some bash documentation that `<` redirection redirects the input to the first SimpleCommand (before the first pipe), so it should redirect `file1` on `cat` then redirect `cat`'s output to `tr`, so it should only output `Bnjur` and nothing else, so why do we have to press enter to exit the command ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please try to write a title that lets someone know what the specific behavior is without needing to click through and read the body.

Comment: Basically, though: Each process has only one stdin. When you give two conflicting specifications, only one will win, and processing is left-to-right, so the one on the right is the winner. You're telling `tr` to get its input from `cat` but also to get its input from `file1`; only one of those two things can happen because each process has only a single stdin.

Comment: No, `file1` is not being redirected to `cat`.   `tr` is taking its input from `file1`, the output of `cat` is going nowhere, and `cat` is reading input from the tty.

Comment: If you want the `<file1` to apply to the whole pipeline, instead write `{ cat | tr -d o; } <file1` (though obvs., there's no good reason to do that instead of `tr -d o <file1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `< file1` redirection only applies to the `tr` command, not the entire pipeline.

So `cat` is reading from the original standard input, which is connected to the terminal. It's hanging because it's waiting for you to type something.

Meanwhile, `tr` is reading from the file. It exits when it finishes processing the file.

Once you type something, `cat` will write it to the pipe. Since `tr` has exited, there's no reader on the pipe, so `cat` will get a `SIGPIPE` signal and terminate.

If you want the redirection to apply to `cat`, use

```
cat < file1 | tr -d 'o'
```

If you want it to apply to the entire pipeline, you can group it in a subshell:

```
( cat | tr -d '0' ) < file1
```

Comment: Parens and not curly braces in the grouping example?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I originally used braces. But since the redirection and pipeline forces it to run in a subprocess anyway, I didn't see a need to avoid a subshell. And I hate the extra `;` you have to use with braces, it's so easy to forget it.

Comment: This is very clarifying thing, thanks, but I have one question remaining: On [this documentation](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/grr/SystemsProgrammingBook/Book/Chapter5-WritingYourOwnShell.pdf) It says that for the following `A | B | C | D > outfile < infile 2> errfile`, infile is redirected to the first simple command `A` (Page 2), so shouldn't my `file1` be redirected to `cat` instead of `tr` in my example?

Comment: That's not the way standard shell commands are parsed. That textbook is implementing their own shell.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting input from file into tr, cat itself has no input and is thus taking input from stdin.  Try this instead.

```
cat file1 | tr -d 'o'
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the OP gets their original behavior, which is the question they actually asked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm trying to reproduce this behavior, not to find a way to redirect the input to cat